# Background image are not loaded in HiQPDF

Tags: html, model-view-controller, html-to-pdf, hiqpdf

I am using HiQPDF to convert HTML to PDF. Everything working fine but background images are not displayed in converted PDF file. Please check below code and suggest me what I am doing wrong. Please note I am using MVC with .Net 4.7 and using HiQPDF version 10.

```
public ActionResult PdfDownload(string slug)
    {
        var dto = _theMonthlyFrontService.GetMonthlyDetail(slug);


        var html = this.RenderView("view", dto).Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("{%WebsiteUrl%}", "");

        var htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf { SerialNumber = "HiqPdfKey" };
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.PageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.Margins.Top = 50;
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.Margins.Bottom = 50;

        var pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToMemory(html, "http://localhost/");

        FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdfBuffer, "application/pdf")
        {
            FileDownloadName = "download.pdf"
        };

        return fileResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the css and found that background images were not visiable due to  some opacity and z-index CSS. So I have applied the following css and now the images are displayed fine

```
.large-gallery {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    z-index : auto !important;
}
```